# Is compileOnSave flag being supported by Sublime Text?

Tags: angular, typescript, sublimetext, angular-cli

I use Sublime Text IDE (version 1 I guess) and noticed in my tsconfig.json this flag:

```
"compileOnSave": false,
```

However, my TS files gets compiled to JS files every time I save them. So it means this does not work in my environment? How could I make it working - stop compiling files after save?

I am interested in this, because I noticed many people gets problems with compiling process at some point. So I want to understand this better (Webpack, IDE, Typescript etc. - many things involved, so quite a lot to understand here...)

Sublime Text info:

[image]

Comment: please add a comment if downvoting (I wont downvote you back)

Comment: Sublime is not an IDE, and as such it only builds when you tell it to. If your typescript is getting automatically compiled, that would indicate that you either have a package installed that's doing it and ignoring the setting, or possibly something outside of Sublime is watching the directory and compiling.

Comment: Are you sure you're on Sublime version 1? That's quite old at this point (even Sublime 2 hasn't been updated in years as all development has been for Sublime Text 3 for a while now).

Comment: @OdatNurd I have added screenshot of what info I see if I click "About Sublime Text". SO I assume its the first version...

Comment: Build numbers that start with 3 are Sublime Text 3, so you're using the latest stable build of Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I would check the list of packages you have installed to see if any of them is trying to do something compile-on-save related. Now that we know you're using a recent version of Sublime I can say with more assurance that it's definitely not doing something like that on it's own.

Comment: @OdatNurd - thank you very much! Now I understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compileOnSave` flag is a specific flags used by `atom-typescript` for the Atom editor.
It is not a part of the official TypeScript configuration.

That said, I don't know if there is a sublime plug in that would re-use the same flag for the same purpose.

Comment: That is what I tend to think as well after googling, but thought it makes no sense that Angular CLI sets this flag for me (the one that uses Sublime...). I wonder why it does that..?

Comment: Because some people use those IDEs. :)  That's an area of improvement of the tooling out there in general -- customization of the environment based on how the user uses it. It is not a simple topic thou. Maybe `editorconfig` is one solution. :)